# On a mission vs in a mission

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I know the correct term is "man on a mission", but in any instance "man in a mission" is correct?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: You could probably contrive one..."Stepping into the mission station, he was now a man in a mission".

Comment: @KillingTime I thought along the same lines. "He was a man in a mission, having been given a bed by a religious charity"

Comment: The loss of his radio made it impossible to contact his companions. He went at once from being on a mission to being in a mission. No completion. No exit. He might still arrive at the transfer point, but without the means to verify his identity, imprisonment and death were the best he could hope for.